# Why does LibGDX SpriteBatch use triangles instead of quads?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm digging into the LibGDX [SpriteBatch class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) as I'm going to be writing my own batching utility for a set of square geometry, and I'm wondering why it uses `GL_TRIANGLES` as its primitive type, rather than `GL_QUADS`?

Everything drawn by a SpriteBatch is a quad so would it not be more performant to set up the vertices and indices to use quads instead?

Comment: Essentially every quad consist of two triangles, I'm not familiar with the inner workings but performance wise it "should" not matter, Every 3D object on a computer is drawn by triangles. This is because a triangle is always "flat". In other words, a tripod is always stable and not wobbly like a 4 legged table can be.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I thought there may be a benefit from having to send less vertices and indices to the GPU from the CPU (4 vertices for each quad rather than 6, batched into thousands), which the GPU would indeed compute as triangles once received. So just an improvement in the amount of data to transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons that may come to mind is the fact that GL_QUADS is not aviailable in GLES2 and the engine is meant to be cross-platform.

Comment: Ah that makes sense when LibGDX is trying to provide compatibility with low end mobile devices. Thanks!

Comment: High end devices also use OpenGL ES.